# How to retain data on custom page when back/next button clicked when the data is taken from a file?

Tags: nsis

I have written a custom component page which is having a rich text box and that text box shows the information which is read from the "component.rtf" file. When I go first time on my custom page it shows me rich text box filled with data, but when I click next or back button and come back to custom page again at that time it shows me the rich text box as blank. It shows nothing.
I have written following code for my custom page-

```
;-------Custom page variables---------
Var Dialog
Var CustomHeaderText
Var CustomSubText
Var path
Var temp1
Var CONTROL
;-------------------------------------
Page custom nsDialogsPage 
;------Custom page function----------
Function nsDialogsPage

    StrCpy $CustomHeaderText "Components of My Installer"
    StrCpy $CustomSubText "Detail list of components are"
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $CustomHeaderText  $CustomSubText 
    !define SF_RTF 2
    !define EM_STREAMIN 1097

    nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD "RichEdit20A" ${ES_READONLY}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${WS_EX_STATICEDGE} 0 10u 100% 110u ''
    Pop $CONTROL

    FileOpen $4 "$path\components.rtf" r
    StrCpy $0 $CONTROL

    SendMessage $CONTROL ${EM_EXLIMITTEXT} 0 0x7fffffff
    ; set EM_AUTOURLDETECT to detect URL automatically
    SendMessage $CONTROL 1115 1 0

    System::Get /NoUnload "(i, i .R0, i .R1, i .R2) iss"
    Pop $2
    System::Call /NoUnload "*(i 0, i 0, k r2) i .r3"

    System::Call /NoUnload "user32::SendMessage(i r0, i ${EM_STREAMIN}, i ${SF_RTF}, i r3) i.s"

    loop:
        Pop $0
        StrCmp $0 "callback1" 0 done
        System::Call /NoUnload "kernel32::ReadFile(i $4, i $R0, i $R1, i $R2, i 0)"
        Push 0 # callback's return value
        System::Call /NoUnload "$2"
    goto loop
    done:
        System::Free $2
        System::Free $3
        FileClose $4

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
;--------Custom page function end------------
```

In above code it reads the file "components.rtf" and displays it. Can someone tell me how to write the code which will retain this data when I will click Back/Next button on component page.?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Perhaps you are overwriting $path on another page? Add `MessageBox MB_OK $4` after `FileOpen` to make sure you are able to open the file.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Var Dialog
Var CustomHeaderText
Var CustomSubText
Var path
#Var temp1
Var CONTROL
;-------------------------------------
Page custom nsDialogsPage 
;------Custom page function----------
Function nsDialogsPage

    StrCpy $CustomHeaderText "Components of My Installer"
    StrCpy $CustomSubText "Detail list of components are"
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $CustomHeaderText  $CustomSubText 
    !define SF_RTF 2
    !define EM_STREAMIN 1097

    nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD "RichEdit20A" ${ES_READONLY}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${WS_EX_STATICEDGE} 0 10u 100% 110u ''
    Pop $CONTROL

    FileOpen $4 "$path\components.rtf" r
    StrCpy $0 $CONTROL

    SendMessage $CONTROL ${EM_EXLIMITTEXT} 0 0x7fffffff
    ; set EM_AUTOURLDETECT to detect URL automatically
    SendMessage $CONTROL 1115 1 0

    System::Get /NoUnload "(i, i .R0, i .R1, i .R2) iss"
    Pop $2
    System::Call /NoUnload "*(i 0, i 0, k r2) i .r3"

    System::Call /NoUnload "user32::SendMessage(i r0, i ${EM_STREAMIN}, i ${SF_RTF}, i r3) i.s"

    loop:
        Pop $0
        StrCmp $0 "callback1" 0 done
        System::Call /NoUnload "kernel32::ReadFile(i $4, i $R0, i $R1, i $R2, i 0)"
        Push 0 # callback's return value
        System::Call /NoUnload "$2"
    goto loop
    done:
        System::Free $2
        System::Free $3
        FileClose $4

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
; Create a RTF file
InitPluginsDir
StrCpy $path "$PluginsDir" ; Set $path used by the custom page
FileOpen $0 "$path\components.rtf" w
FileWrite $0 '{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard{Show {\b Me}}\par{http://example.com/#Funny}\par{Goodbye}}'
FileClose $0
FunctionEnd

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: No..I'm not overriding the $path variable anywhere. I also checked whether file is opening or not. File is getting opened without any errors. Still it is not showing the text in rich text box when i am coming back from next page.

Comment: Yes @Anders, your code has the same problem in it. I tried your solution.

Comment: @VishalPatil NSIS version? Windows version?

Comment: NSIS version is 2.46 and windows 7 64-bit